# Google Login xcode swift 3 xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode

Im having a bit of an issue signing into google and need help fixing the problem.

```
anonymousButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
anonymousButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "770972824361-ei33geb3pt43fgjqrhli0lg95dpeu6pf.apps.googleusercontent.com"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

The last line of the GID is giving an issue. Plus when running the app simulator it gives me a white screen.

Comment: What issue exactly?

Comment: Setting the delegate to self requires to adopt the corresponding protocol.

Comment: how can i fix the issue I'm trying to sign users in with google

Comment: Follow the suggestions of the warnings / errors you get. I'm not familiar with Google API.

Comment: well contact me and ill show you the issue on Skype

Comment: You probably get an error *Can not assign a value of 'TypeA' to 'TypeB'*. TypeB is the protocol you have to adopt (add to the class declaration line) and to implement the required methods.

Comment: you gonna have to see to know the issue

Comment: You gonna have to describe the issue in the question.

Comment: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self        is says i can't  assign value to login view controller to type GIDSignInDelegate

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote in my third comment. **You have to adopt the protocol GIDSignInDelegate**

Comment: how do i fix that? i'm new to this

Comment: Please read my comments: Add `GIDSignInDelegate` to the class declaration line and implement the required methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using objc, but the concept is the same for swift:

```
@interface SomeClassHere : NSObject <GIDSignInDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation SomeClassHere

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
 ...
 }
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
...
}
@end
```

Once you've added `<GIDSignInDelegate>` to your class definition the error should disappear.  But you will get warnings about unimplemented methods.  You need to implement the two methods I provided.  Looks like you need to read the documentation on [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Comment: how do I fix this? FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: {(user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else {